# What is $0^0$, in ordinal exponentiation?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

A student of mine pointed out to me that if we define ordinal exponentiation the usual way (by recursion), then we have $0^0=1$ (which is fine), and thus 
$$
0^\omega=\sup\{0^n:n<\omega\}=1,
$$
instead of the expected answer $0$.

What is the common resolution of this issue?

Comment: Jech _Set Theory_ (3rd Millennium ed.), Hrbacek & Jech _Introduction to Set Theory_, Just & Weese _Discovering Modern Set Theory, vol I_, Roitman, _Introduction to Modern Set Theory_, Kunen, _Set Theory_ (new ed.) and Komjáth & Totik _Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory_ all seem to fall victim to this oversight. It seems the **common** resolution of this issue is either pretend it doesn't exist or  assume that everyone knows what we "really mean".

Comment: Boaz, you could probably replace $\beta$ in all the recursive definitions by $\beta+1$ or $\beta>0$. Or just use the order-theoretic definitions: sum of orders, reverse lexicographic order, and that terrible dictionary-like order on finite sequences. In that second case, $0^\omega=0$ by the same argument that $0^{\aleph_0}=0$ as cardinal exponentiation.

Comment: @arjafi I was almost sure that Jech defined the operations using limits (so it is the correct definition), and I was right. But in turn, he only defines limits of _nondecreasing_ sequences, which is incomplete. So he's a victim of an issue of a different kind.

Comment: (... running to correct some notes of mine!)

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Yes, technically in Jech $0^\alpha$ isn't defined for $\alpha \geq \omega$. In detail it's a slightly different issue, but it boils down to overlooking that $\langle 0^n : n < \omega \rangle$ isn't nondecreasing, which to me is the central failing these have in common.

Answer (score 10):

You probably just need to define $0^\omega$ as the "limit" of the $0^n$ for $n < \omega$, instead of just the supremum. Or you can define $0^\beta$ as a special case in the definition of the exponentiation.

For any ordinal $\alpha$ other than $0$, the sequence $\alpha^n$ is increasing so the limit of the sequence is its sup. But of course for $\alpha = 0$ we get a decreasing sequence $(1, 0, 0, 0\dots)$ and its limit is its minimum, which is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, there is this trick/general idea which is often neglected, but it comes in handy in this case.

Let's look at sum first: instead of separating three cases for non-zero limit ordinals, successor ordinals and $0$, we can define $$\alpha+\beta:=\begin{cases} \alpha&\text{if }\beta=0\\ \sup\left\{(\alpha+\gamma)^+\,:\,\gamma<\beta\right\}&\text{if }\beta\ne0\end{cases}$$
in just two cases.

Often, these constructions go like this:

1. define case $g(0)$
2. construct $g(\beta^+)$ in terms of $g(\beta)$
3. take the "limit as $\gamma\to\beta$" of $g(\gamma)$ for limit ordinals
4. (optional) realise, in hindsight, that you were taking the limit of $g(\gamma^+)$ all along, and that this approach is actually comprehensive of $g(\beta^+)$ as well.

For the concrete example, you can use the trick

> $$\alpha^\beta=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\beta=0\\ \sup\left\{\alpha^\gamma\cdot\alpha\,:\,\gamma<\beta\right\}&\text{if }\beta\ne 0\end{cases}$$

Though I agree that the introduction of a notion of $\limsup\limits_{\gamma\to\beta}:=\min\limits_{\gamma<\beta}\sup\limits_{\gamma\le\delta<\beta}$ could be useful in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y$ be ordinals.

Let $F(x,y)$ be the set of functions $f:x\to y$ such that $$\{z\in x: f(z)\ne 0\}\; \text { is finite.}$$ (In the absence of the axiom of choice, by a finite set I mean a bijective image of a member of $\omega$ .)

For $f,g \in F(x,y)$ let $f<^*g$ iff for the LARGEST $z$ such that $f(z)\ne g(z)$ we have $f(z)\in g(z).$

DEFINITION. $y^x$ is the ordinal whose $\epsilon$-order is isomorphic to the $<^*$-order on $F(x,y).$

From this it is immediate that $0^x=0.$

It is convenient in analysis to (sometimes) have $0^0=1,$ as in " Let $p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_jx^j$ " where it is understood  that $a_0x^0=a_0$ when $x=0.$ And also because $x^x$ converges to $1$ as $x\to 0^+.$

Of course you can define the ordinal $0^0$ to be $1$ if you want. This will introduce its own notational inconveniences.